# Cakephp - one variable accessible in view and controller

Tags: cakephp, variables, global

I want to define an array which I can use in `AppController` and in the default layout.

How can I do this in CakePHP?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
$this->set('arr', array('one', 'two'));

// Accessible in controller as 
$this->viewVars['arr'];

// Accessible in view/layout as
echo $arr;
```

Comment: in CakePhp4 replaced with this : $this->viewBuilder()->getVar('arr');

Answer (score 2):

If you set any variable in AppController beforeRender() function,and set that variable,then you can access easily that variable anywhere in the view files

```
function beforeRender() {
    parent::beforeRender();
    $sample_arr = array("abc","xyz");
    $this->set('sample_arr',$sample_arr);
}
```

In your Layout File Just Print that Array like

```
print_r($sample_arr);
```

Comment: Is it safe to go like that?

Answer (score 0):

from here:

[cakephp set function](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html)

```
// First you pass data from the controller:

$this->set('color', 'pink');

// Then, in the view, you can utilize the data:
?>

You have selected <?php echo $color; ?> icing for the cake.
```

So for your situation:

```
$arr = array('stuff', 'more stuff');

$this->set('arr', $arr);

// then in the layout
print_r($arr);
```